QScreen geometry returning invalid values on multi-monitor displays?
I've got a PyQt5 application that needs to run on a variety of different PC's with different single- or multi-monitor display set-ups. It needs to arrange multiple child windows across multiple screens programmatically based on optimising the space available. However PyQt5 is returning some very confusing and apparently wrong values for the available screen geometry.
On one test PC, the Windows desktop arrangement is like this:

All three of these displays have a scale setting of 150%. The large displays have a display resolution of 3840 x 2160.
When I iterate QApplication.screens() and get the geometry() of each of the screens, I get (from left to right):
[PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(-2880, 1607, 2880, 1620),
PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 3840, 2160),
PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(5760, 0, 3840, 2160)]

I don't understand why the right-hand monitor has an origin point of 5760,0 if the centre display is only 3840px wide? This essentially creates an island between the two large monitors which, according to the screen geometry, isn't even there. An unscientific mockup of it would look like this:

The numbers between the left and centre monitor look fine, but the right-hand monitor is off.
Furthermore, if I want to programmatically move a window onto the right hand monitor, the position it expects in a move() call would be 5760,0. Calling move(3840,0), which feels like it ought to place the window on the right-hand monitor, ends up partway across the central monitor.
There's an apparent inconsistency between the scaling values for position and size, and I am struggling to find a workaround for it. I can't seem to find a screen parameter (logicalDotsPerInch, devicePixelRatio etc.) that I could use to compensate for the gap, without ruining the valid values between the centre and left monitors.
Has anyone encountered this before and worked out a reliable way of getting the PyQt-friendly dimensions of all the screens, properly scaled and ready for use in a move()?
The Windows process is DPI-aware, which is essential for other reasons, and the Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling attribute on the application is set to True already, though changing it to False doesn't seem to make any difference.

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/highdpi.html#device-independent-screen-geometry

I forgot to mention I'd already read the docs.
The documentation describes the problem: "This will produce an islands-of-screens type virtual desktop geometry". But how am I supposed to "use that list to reason about available screen geometry" when the available information gives inconsistent values between the screens, with no obvious way of determining which values are scaled and which aren't?

You can get the different scaling with QScreen dotsPerInch functions. I don't understand why you want to use (3840,0) instead of what QScreen provides. If you want to move the window to a different screen, just use the geometry that screen provides, don't "assume" one.

QScreen doesn't have a dotsPerInch parameter. It has logicalDotsPerInch, where all 3 monitors report as 144, and physicalDotsPerInch where the larger monitors report 153.36 and the smaller display 212.38, and I can't find a way of translating that back into something useful.
The user request is to have a single QDialog that spans multiple monitors in the most efficient way possible, and I can't do that well if I can't compensate for these 'islands'' between the reported geometry. If I just wanted to use one screen size, I would use the geometry of that QScreen.

I should add that all 3 screens report a devicePixelRatio of 1.0, so the answer's not there either

I obviously meant "all the dotsPerInch related functions". But, yes, I was thinking about a different aspect, and devicePixelRatio should be the correct one, but if you get the same value, then there's probably little you can do. If you plan on having a window that large, you may just consider the leftmost screen as reference for positioning, with the width assumed on the geometry of each screen. Note, though, that scaling may change depending on where the majority of the window (normally, the center) is: on Windows, that causes the window to scale when changing screen.

Did you try the various env variables listed in the docs?

Sorry, I wasn't getting notifications on this so didn't see this reply until now, having coming back to this problem after a break. It looks like QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS might be worth a look, I'll see how that goes
